# Enterprise Tester: how to see attachments or pictures linked to test scripts when executing tests?

Tags: tools

I'm currently evaluating [Enterprise Tester](http://www.enterprisetester.com/) for managing tests (it is simlar to HP qulaity center) and have the following question.

When creating tests (so called "test scripts") it is possible to attach pictures to the tests. However when actually executing the tests I see no easy possibility to look at the pictures without actually leaving the test execution.

My question: is anybody using Enterprise Tester and knows how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I’m the Product Manager for [Enterprise Tester](http://www.enterpristester.com).

Currently, the attachments do not propagate to the tests in the execution sets however it is certainly an enhancement that we intend to add in an upcoming release.    This enhancement is logged as TMS-1497.  To access the attachment you will need to navigate back to the test case in the Script Library by using the link at the top of the execution screen.

Comment: Hi Hans, this is now a feature in v4.3 due for release early next month - http://blogs.catchlimited.com/2012/08/enterprise-tester-4-3-you-asked-for-it/